# Python stack contents are overwritten when passed to a function

Tags: python, function, python-2.7, stack

I wrote a quick Python function to reverse the contents of a stack.

```
def ReverseStack(input_stack):
    oldStack = input_stack
    newStack = Stack()

    while not oldStack.isEmpty():
        item = oldStack.pop()
        newStack.push(item)
    return newStack

s = Stack()
s.push('hello')
s.push('world')
s.push('I')
s.push('live')
s.push('underwater')

new = ReverseStack(s)

print "\nOriginal stack..."
while not s.isEmpty():
    print s.pop()

print "\nNew stack..."
while not new.isEmpty():
    print new.pop()
```

However, when I go to print the contents of each stack (original and reversed) it appears as though all of the contents of the original stack have been removed via the pop method. Which confuses me, since I passed it as a parameter to a function that creates a temporary stack to pop the contents out of. I thought this way would have left the original intact.

My question is why does this happen, and what is the best way of correcting it? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line

```
oldStack = input_stack
```

makes oldStack a reference to the same object, not a copy. You need to use

```
import copy
```

to copy arbitrary objects.

Probably the best way to correct it is to iterate through the stack, rather than pop'ing items off of it.

Possible useful reference: http://www.python-course.eu/deep_copy.php

Comment: Nice, I knew it had to be something like this, I just didn't know how to go about resolving it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You passed a mutable object to ReverseStack and ReverseStack mutated it. Python doesn't copy objects when passed to a function (that would be expensive) so you either have to copy it yourself or write functions that don't modify what's passed in... unless that's the point of the function in the first place.